# Having trouble adding Braintree to my angular2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, braintree

Having trouble adding Braintree to my angular2 app

I just want to get a basic version wired up to my sandbox Braintree account, so I can see a transaction.

The create code below seems to work.
But when I click submit it goes to this end point and all I see is a white screen and no transaction in sandbox: **"/transaction-endpoint"**

**I've installed these:**

npm install --save braintree-web
npm install @types/braintree-web@3.0.1

**This is my ts file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var braintree:any;

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'PaymentComponent',  
  templateUrl: 'payment.component.html'
})

export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(){
  }  

  ngOnInit() {
        //I have a authorization token from the documentation.  
        var authorization = 'RemovedFromStackoverflow';

        var submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

        braintree.client.create({authorization: authorization}, function (clientErr: any, clientInstance: any) {

          //No error occurs
          console.log(clientErr);
          console.log(clientInstance);

          if (clientErr) {
            // Handle error in client creation
            return;
          }

          braintree.hostedFields.create({
            client: clientInstance,
            styles: {
              'input': {
                'font-size': '14pt'
              },
              'input.invalid': {
                'color': 'red'
              },
              'input.valid': {
                'color': 'green'
              }
            },
            fields: {
              number: {
                selector: '#card-number',
                placeholder: '4111 1111 1111 1111'
              },
              cvv: {
                selector: '#cvv',
                placeholder: '123'
              },
              expirationDate: {
                selector: '#expiration-date',
                placeholder: '10/2019'
              }
            }
          }, function (hostedFieldsErr, hostedFieldsInstance) {
            if (hostedFieldsErr) {
              // Handle error in Hosted Fields creation
              return;
            }

             submit.removeAttribute('disabled');
          });
        });
  }
}
```

**These are the scripts I've added to my index.html file:**

```
<!-- Load the Client component. -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.6.3/js/client.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load the Hosted Fields component. -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.6.3/js/hosted-fields.min.js"></script>
```

**This is my html file (form from documentation)**

```
        <form id="checkout-form" action="/transaction-endpoint" method="post">
          <div id="error-message"></div>

          <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
          <div class="hosted-field" id="card-number"></div>

          <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
          <div class="hosted-field" id="cvv"></div>

          <label for="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
          <div class="hosted-field" id="expiration-date"></div>

          <input type="hidden" name="payment-method-nonce">
          <input type="submit" value="Pay $10" disabled>
        </form>
```

Comment: Are you including the library with a script tag? What is your build process?

Comment: I'm using gulp serve.dev to run my systemjs app

Comment: @rob I havent got any script tag, I currently have an empty html file and the above ts file. I used npm install --save braintree-web AND npm install @types/braintree-web@3.0.1 to install it. Not sure what else to do.

Comment: For any dependency you use you either need to import it with an ES6 import statement or include it with a script tag.

Comment: @rob I've added the script now and it seems to work. To use braintain will I need to use nodejs? seems like i need to. I just want a client side payment system. So I've used the javascript SDK

Comment: @rob I've updated my question above to show you where I'm at now. Almost their I think. Let me know your thoughts?